# Heatmap, visualizing on negative/positive values with Cartography

Tags: visualization, geography, geographics

I want to create a heatmap in relation with a CityMap.

A example of my dataset is:

```
data = {{GeoPosition[{52.4221, 4.79205}], 
  0.000972465}, {GeoPosition[{52.4264, 4.84578}], 
  0.0010099}, {GeoPosition[{52.4177, 4.82724}], 
  0.00112501}, {GeoPosition[{52.4214, 4.88542}], 
  0.0177381}, {GeoPosition[{52.4205, 
    4.87914}], -0.0298788}, {GeoPosition[{52.4291, 4.85623}], 
  0.00296465}, {GeoPosition[{52.4291, 4.85623}], 
  0.00217909}, {GeoPosition[{52.4198, 
    4.88569}], -0.000724821}, {GeoPosition[{52.4208, 
    4.88559}], -0.00372882}, {GeoPosition[{52.42, 4.85725}], 
  0.0016284}, {GeoPosition[{52.42, 4.85725}], 
  0.00107895}, {GeoPosition[{52.42, 4.85725}], 
  0.0013905}, {GeoPosition[{52.4234, 4.88412}], 
  0.000964795}, {GeoPosition[{52.4236, 4.88547}], 
  0.000709201}, {GeoPosition[{52.4228, 4.88614}], 
  0.00030988}, {GeoPosition[{52.418, 
    4.88252}], -0.000596178}, {GeoPosition[{52.4192, 
    4.88384}], -0.000621033}, {GeoPosition[{52.4183, 
    4.88494}], -0.000895842}, {GeoPosition[{52.417, 
    4.88418}], -0.000822613}, {GeoPosition[{52.4177, 4.87921}], 
  0.000309823}, {GeoPosition[{52.4378, 4.86506}], 
  0.00184676}, {GeoPosition[{52.4378, 4.86506}], 
  0.00188428}, {GeoPosition[{52.4196, 
    4.88231}], -0.000894745}, {GeoPosition[{52.4188, 
    4.88161}], -0.000619265}, {GeoPosition[{52.422, 4.88651}], 
  0.00151762}, {GeoPosition[{52.4197, 4.88069}], 0.00505053}}
```

In this data I have the Latitude and Longitude and a value. This value can be positive or negative. This is important because the legend must show the reader how to interpretate the values (the values are water highs in a city like Amsterdam).

My approach is like

```
data1=WeightedData[data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2]]]

GeoSmoothHistogram[data1, PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Below], 
 GeoScaleBar -> "Metric", Mesh -> 6, MeshStyle -> {Red, Dotted}, 
 GeoRange -> {{52.2967, 52.4214}, {4.7696, 5.0190}}, 
 ImageSize -> 1000]
```

When I use `WeightedData` in combination with negative values, I get an error (Mathematica 12.0). Who has a suggestion to create this citymap?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think weights can be negative. Try `GeoRegionValuePlot`

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[data,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Below],
 GeoScaleBar -> "Metric",
 GeoRange -> {{52.2967, 52.5214}, {4.7696, 5.0190}}]
```

[image]